# Spyder IDE 5.3.3 (Python 3.8) execution of TCL script hangs in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, tcl, spyder

I have a python script that runs without problems when I run it from the Windows command shell or Visual Studio 2019. When I run it in the Spyder IDE, executing the TCL script hangs. I'm using the following to run the TCL script:

```py
subprocess.call("script.tcl")
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that script running with `tclsh` or `wish`? Only the former really works properly as a subprocess thing on Windows because `tclsh` is built as a console program and terminates when the end of the script is reached, whereas `wish` is built as a GUI program and does not (it instead runs the event loop until the last window is closed).

The default binding for `.tcl` files on Windows is against `wish`. I'm not convinced that that's the right choice, but it's how it is.